# Cauchy's theorem proof (sequences)

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-problem

Proof thr following of cauchy's theorems:

If (a$_m)m\geq$0 is a convergent sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ and $b=\lim_{m\to \infty} a_m$ then

$$\lim_{m\to \infty} \frac{a_0 + a_1 + ... + a_m}{m+1}= b $$

NOTE: We have only recently started learning about series and sequences and can therefor only use very limited definitions and theorems such as the definition of a sequence and subsequence,definition of convergent sequences,... and little more. So the most basic proof would be usefull.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{a_0+\dots+a_m}{m+1}-b=\frac{(a_0-b)+\dots+(a_m-b)}{m+1}$.

Comment: I've come this far : https://ibb.co/kfLwnw

Comment: It's OK to write this in LaTeX, too. The sequence $(a_n)$ converges to $b$, so there is $N_1$ such that for all $n>N_1$, $|a_n-b|<\varepsilon$. Also, there is $N_2$ such that for all $n>N_2$, $$\frac{|a_1-b|+\dots+|a_{N_1}-b|}{n+1}<\varepsilon.$$ (Note that the numerator does not depend on $N_2$ or $n$.) Now put all this together to get the estimate you need.

Comment: How do we know the second premisse? ( The existence of $N_2$ )

Comment: Reread what I wrote: The numerator does not depend on $N_2$. Once we fix $N_1$, it's just a big constant. Now you can finish the rest of it.

Comment: Nothing has changed. You choose $N_1$, then you choose $N_2$, so now you have both $N_1$ and $N_2$. You must have $n>N_1$ and $n>N_2$, so you let $N=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$ and let $n>N$. It's one of the most basic tricks in analysis proofs.

Comment: Thank you i will make sure i understand the proces you explained!

Comment: [This discussion has been moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69699/discussion-between-alexander-burstein-and-michelle-b).